# Adding a userID (FK) to MySQL table from NextJS/Prisma

Tags: mysql, next.js, prisma

I am creating an online recipe website where users can sign in and post their recipes. I am using NextJS, Prisma, and MySQL DB. I am authenticating users using NextAuth and credentials provider, with a username and password. The problem is that when I want to link my users table and my recipe tables with a foreign key constraint of userID, so that each recipe is linked to a specific user. I am having trouble figuring out the best way to get the current session, which only consists of the username, and sending the usersID to link with the created recipe. The userID is an auto-incremented PK that is only accessible from the prisma backend. Any idea how I can link the user to a recipe with only the nextauth credentials (username and password).

[image: Users Table]

[image: Recipes Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your NextAuth configuration, you can customise what gets added to the `JWT` and the session when a user logs in.

Here's how you can add `userId` to `JWT` and session:

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import Providers from 'next-auth/providers'
import Adapters from 'next-auth/adapters'
import prisma from '../../../db' // your prisma client

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Providers.Credentials({
      // Your credentials provider configuration
    })
  ],
  adapter: Adapters.Prisma.Adapter({ prisma }),
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  callbacks: {
    async jwt(token, user) {
      // Initial sign in
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id
      }
      return token
    },
    async session(session, token) {
      // Add property to session, like `userId`
      session.userId = token.id
      return session
    }
  }
})
```

In your API routes, you can now access `userId directly from the session:

```js
import { getSession } from "next-auth/client";

export default async (req, res) => {
  const session = await getSession({ req });
  console.log(session.userId);  // you can use this id to link the user with the recipe
  // your code here
}
```

This way, whenever a user logs in, their `userId` is included in the `JWT` and session data.